# Tomcat6 No JDK Found

Tags: java, linux, oracle, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm ssh'd into my server (Ubuntu 12.04) and no matter what I set for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME tomcat6 doesn't want to start:

```
me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33/bin

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ echo $JRE_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33/jre

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ sudo service tomcat6 start
 * no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ sudo service tomcat6 start
 * no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ ls $JAVA_HOME
bin        db       jre  LICENSE  README.html    register_ja.html     src.zip
COPYRIGHT  include  lib  man      register.html  register_zh_CN.html  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt

me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33$ ls $JAVA_HOME/bin
appletviewer  HtmlConverter  java     javap     jdb    jps         jstat      native2ascii  rmic         serialver   wsgen
apt           idlj           javac    javaws    jhat   jrunscript  jstatd     orbd          rmid         servertool  wsimport
ControlPanel  jar            javadoc  jconsole  jinfo  jsadebugd   jvisualvm  pack200       rmiregistry  tnameserv   xjc
extcheck      jarsigner      javah    jcontrol  jmap   jstack      keytool    policytool    schemagen    unpack200
```

I was looking at tomcat6's init.d script, and I found some custom logic that searches for openjdk. I don't want to use openjdk, I purposely installed oracle! Here's a snippit of the init.d script (which I didn't write):

```
# this is a work-around until there is a suitable runtime replacement 
# for dpkg-architecture for arch:all packages
# this function sets the variable OPENJDKS
find_openjdks()
{
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS=$jvmdir
                fi
        done
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS="${OPENJDKS} ${jvmdir}"
                fi
        done
}

# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
# defined in $DEFAULT)

OPENJDKS=""
find_openjdks
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-ibm"

# Look for the right JVM to use
for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
    if [ -r "$jdir/bin/java" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
        JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
    fi
done
export JAVA_HOME
```

I had to remove the openjdk from /usr/lib/jvm because stupid tomcat kept finding it and using it, even though my JAVA_HOME variable was set to use oracle's java.

Help please? I have no idea how to fix this. I'm using maven and maven works perfectly fine with the way i've set the JAVA_HOME variable.

**Edit:**

I opened the init.d tomcat script and changed this line:

```
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-ibm"
```

to this:

```
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-ibm"
```

(I just added my path `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33` to the string)
And suddenly tomcat booted and ran with my oracle java. I guess this works, but that can't have been the best way to do it.

**Edit:**

StephenC:

```
me@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm$ sudo bash
root@myserver:/usr/lib/jvm# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo bash
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I suspect that the problem is that *your* $JAVA_HOME environment variable is not being passed through `sudo` to the command it is running.  **The manual entry certainly implies that it won't be!!**  (Your experiment seems to imply otherwise, but I suspect that something else is confusing things ...)

I'm not sure what the best long-term fix for this, but the alternatives include:

- Setting $JAVA_HOME in the catalina.sh script
- Setting $JAVA_HOME in the tomcat init.d script
- Some distros have a convention that all distro-provided service launch scripts pick up local config overrides from a file in /etc ...
- Setting $JAVA_HOME in the shell RC file for the "tomcat" user (probably a bad idea)
- Tweaking the sudoers config so that $JAVA_HOME is passed (definitely a bad idea!)
- Using the "-E" option ...

IMO, it is a bad idea to rely on *your* $JAVA_HOME environment variable when launching a service.  The chances are that you will forget and launch with the wrong JDK by mistake.  Protect yourself.

Comment: Technically it would be the actual tomcat6 user that would be launching java (not root), so is it the case that the environment variable was set for me but not for the tomcat6 user? I've tried to login as tomcat6 with `sudo su - tomcat6` but nothing happens when i excecute that command.

Comment: Technically, yes.  But the problem is the same.  Environment variable settings are not (normally) passed when you use `su` or `sudo`.  (There are command options to override this ... read the respective manual entries.)

Comment: "sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat6" and add
"JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle.1.6.0_33"